# Are there user agents that add whitespace to text sent over HTTP?

Tags: http, browser, trim

*This is more of a technical question than a help question. I'm not interested in knowing if I should `trim()` my input.*

**Are there any user agents (browsers) that add whitespace to text sent over HTTP?** I'm wondering in some cases if trim() is necessary (*aside from users adding whitespace*) because I've never actually seen a browser add anything to a value it's sending (encoding changes aside).

Was there a time in the past when user agents did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a browser add whitespace to a value(but that doesn't mean that much), but I've seen user's do it plenty

Comment: agreed.  trim the pants off it.

Answer (score 0):

I also replace double-spaces with single-spaces (and do the same with double-new lines, etc) after i trim() a string where possible and the original formatting is not very important ("street    x" becomes "street x")

Comment: apparently stackoverflow does too - however, I wouldn't remove double new lines as they might represent new paragraphs of text.

Comment: That's why i said "where... the original formatting is not very important". It's a case-by-case decision. Some times you'd want to replace any number of new lines greater than two to just two, to avoid someone creating pages with nothing but a large number of new lines or br tags (or anything else.)...